# symfony2 routing cannot find controller

Tags: symfony, routes

I am setting up a new symfony2 project
My routing.yml can't find my controller

My controller is located here:

> src/Bank/SNSBundle/Controller/HomeController.php

in my app/config/routing.yml:

```
home:
  path: /blah
  defaults: { _controler: BankSNSBundle:Home:Index}
```

and this is my home controller:

```
<?php

    namespace Bank\SNSBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

    class HomeController extends Controller {

        /**
         * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
         */
        public function IndexAction(){
            return $this->render('BankSNSBundle:Home:index.html.twig', array('name' => "Ralph"));
        }
    }
```

when I go to /blah I get  this error:

> Unable to find the controller for path "/blah". The route is wrongly
>   configured.

can annyone telle me what's wrong with my code?

Ralph

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a Typo:

defaults: { _control**l**er: BankSNSBundle:Home:Index}

(controller with 2 "L")